# Get the result from data.php then convert it to javascript string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I don't really know what to call this. Here is my files

data.php => calculate some random numbers
jscript.js => this echos the result from data.php to a div id

but what i wanted to do on some part is get the value from data.php and then place it to
the style of the div.

```
    $.get('jQuery/data.php?Con&userHP&perc' , { userID: xUserID } ,
    function(output) {
        $('#userHP').html(output).show();
        var o = document.getElementById("userHealthbar");
        o.style.width= result_here ;
    }
);
```

instead of placing the result inside the div /div i want it to the style portion of the div.

P.S: i want the result from data.php to be a variable in javascript.

but i can't seem to make it work.
i hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: If you need to return multiple things from your php script to your javascript, you should output json and process it on the js-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return multiple things from php to javascript, you should use json.

So if you have 2 values you want to return in php, you can do:

```
$html = "your html string";
$value = 4;    // the value you want to return

$array_to_return = array("html" => $html, "value" => $value);

echo json_encode($array_to_return);    // the only thing you echo out in your php!
```

Then, in javascript, you can use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `$.get`:

```
$.getJSON('jQuery/data.php?Con&userHP&perc' , { userID: xUserID } ,
    function(output) {
        $('#userHP').html(output.html).show();
        var o = document.getElementById("userHealthbar");
        o.style.width= output.value ;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery selectors instead of document.getelementById.

Common way:

```
jQuery('#userHealthbar').attr('style', whateverYouGotFromPHP);
```

Better in this case:

```
jQuery('#userHealthbar').width(whateverYouGotFromPHP);
```

D.

Comment: so i'll just put `code jQuery('#userHealthbar').width(data.php);`
cause my problem is how to get the result from data.php to be use as variables in javascript. sorry i am really new to javascript and is just trying to understand it with frustration.